# Future Employers Are/Will Told

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about present & future tenses [here](http://news.yahoo.com/dallas-area-teacher-fired-over-ferguson-tweets-154012279.html):

> Hegwood, who taught English at Duncanville High School, was placed on unpaid leave Monday. She apologized in a statement Thursday and submitted her resignation, but the school board rejected a resignation and instead fired her with cause. That doesn't affect a teacher's pension, but it makes him or her ineligible for unemployment benefits, and ***future employers are told*** the teacher didn't leave in good standing, school district spokeswoman Lari Barager said.

The act of telling happens only in the future with future employers.  So, the present tense in "*future employers* ***are told***..." seems off.  Would "*future employers* ***will be told*** ...." be better?

Comment: It's a perfectly natural use of present tense to reflect *ongoing, habitual* actions. The fact that the relevant employers are all "future" relative to the dismissal makes no difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would the future tense version "*future employers* ***will be told***" be condemned as wrong?

Comment: Both are fine. It's not really any different to *"I will go to school on Monday"*, as against *"I go to school on Monday"*. Where we *might* pluralise *Mondays* to make it more explicit that this is a regular activity, not just something that's going to happen on the coming Monday.

Answer (score 3):

It says *future employers are told*, because it means that when *any* teachers are fired, those teachers' future employers are always told that they were fired in bad circumstances. Because this is a regular practice that happens all the time, the present simple is used.

Comment: Would the future tense version "*future employers* ***will be told***" be condemned as wrong?

Comment: No,, it would just be thinking about it in a different way, that's all :)

Comment: If the context is, 'The practice is that future employers are told...', present plural is okay.

Comment: Why did the writer use “didn’t leave” in good standing instead of saying “doesn’t leave”  @Araucaria